# How to typecast vector into const char*

Tags: visual-c++

I want to parse a txt file and that should be written in excel file i have library fun for excel argument takes const char* im using vectors to parse a file and storing data and passing this vector fun its giving error typecast error its showing my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

vector< vector<string> >  data;


void parse(const char* name)
{
    ifstream in(name);

  string line;

  // read the file
  while ( getline(in,line,'|') ) 
  {
    vector<string> fields;
    std::stringstream    linestream(line);
    for ( int col = 0 ; col < 21 ; col++ ) 
    {
      string f;
      linestream >> f;
      fields.push_back(f);
    }
    data.push_back(fields);
  }

  // output by rows
  for ( vector< vector<string> >::size_type row = 0 ; row < data.size() ; row++ )
  {
    for ( vector<string>::size_type col = 0 ; col < data[row].size() ; col++ ) 
    {
    //  std::vector<char> copy = data;
//char * buffer = &copy[0];
         /*char *buffer = new char[data.size()];
            std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), buffer);*/
        //buffer=static_cast<char *>(data[row]);
        //cout << buffer[row];
        cout << data[row][col];

    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  // output by columns
  /*for ( vector<string>::size_type col = 0 ; col < data[0].size() ; col++ )
  {
    for ( vector< vector<string> >::size_type row = 0 ; row < data.size() ; row++ ) 
    {
      cout << data[row][col] << ",";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }*/
}

static void example1(const char* path)
{

        sheet->Cell(row, col)->Set(data[r][c]);/i need to pass vector into this fun
}


enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

`data[row][col]` is a `std::string`, so `data[row][col].c_str()` gives you the `const char*` that you are looking for.

But if sheet is an Excel sheet COM object, you need to wrap your string in a bstr_t or _variant_t.

BTW, in my Excel automation code I don't see a Cell method in _Worksheet.

Comment: @suneetha If my answer helped you solve the problem, you could be so kind to accept my answer. This will show your question as solved and give me some credit. Thanks.